# Storm example error

Tags: xml, maven, apache-storm, topology

I am running,in local mode,a simple word count topology.When i run the topology with Intellij IDE everything works perfectly and i get a count of the words from the string.However,when i run the topology from Mac's terminal i get the error:

```
A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/topology/IRichSpout
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) 
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
```

I used the commands mvn package and storm jar target/WordCount-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  com.microsoft.example.WordCountTopology while being in the proper files.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `STORM_HOME`. It cannot find the required jars, which should be in `$STORM_HOME/lib`.

Alternatively, you can build a far jar by specifying the `storm-core` dependencies in the `pom.xml` as `<scope>compile</scope>`.